# OutOfMemoryError caused by Drools PhreakPropagationContext & PropagationEntry$Update?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm using Optaplanner version 7.23.0.Final (I've had this issue since a couple of minor versions before as well. This issue might exist even earlier).

The issue is simple: the longer the solver runs the more memory gets used, it continues to go up until our memory limit is reached (4GB in my case). When the memory usage reaches the max, then GC kicks in more than before and the solver runs for a little bit longer until ultimately an OutOfMemoryError is thrown.

If I stop the solver before an OutOfMemoryError is thrown and I start another one, then the memory immediately gets GC'ed and the program is back to 500 megabytes or so.

I've been analyzing several 7GB heapdumps using VisualVM and they all consistently have 2 entries at the top of the memory usage that use up **+95%** of the program's total memory capacity:

```
| Name                                            | Count              | Size                    | Retained |
|-------------------------------------------------|--------------------|-------------------------|----------|
| org.drools.core.common.PhreakPropagationContext | 42,469,685 (49%)   | 4,289,438,185 B (66%)   | n/a      |
| org.drools.core.phreak.PropagationEntry$Update  | 42,445,499 (48.9%) | 2,037,383,952 B (31.4%) | n/a      |
```

When I expand the 2 entries, they contain millions of tiny instances of 101 B instances (for the PhreakPropagationContext type) and 48 B instances (for the PropagationEntry$Update type).

I assume this is not normal? However, if it is normal.. then why is Java throwing an OutOfMemoryError? Why are these things failing to be cleaned up during solving?
Is there anything more that I can provide in order to help in this investigation?

Comment: Looks like a serious issue in drools, please create a issue: https://www.optaplanner.org/community/getHelp.html

Comment: Created here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1736